# In xterm(mintty,bash), how can I open a file in the exist vim process?

Tags: bash, vim

I used to open file in multiple tab

like visual studio or eclipse do.

How can I open the a file into the exist vim process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this:

- run `vim` in a `screen` session, and attach to that from different terminals
- run `vim` in client/server mode

Further reading:

- [Taking Command of the Terminal with GNU Screen](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/285795-taking-command-of-the-terminal-with-gnu-screen-)
- [Using GNU Screen to Manage Persistent Terminal Sessions](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions)
- [Server and client mode in Vim](https://ajayfromiiit.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/server-and-client-mode-in-vim/)
- [How does vim support C/S mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231073/how-does-vim-support-c-s-mode)

Answer (score 1):

From within the vi/vim/gvim editor, you can open a file by typing `:e fileName` (or instead of `fileName` you can use `path/to/fileName`, absolute or relative).

For the multiple file view (multiple-tab idea), first do one of the following:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for a horizontal split
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for a vertical split

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to switch between panes